# Assigning attributes in HTML form or when calling .new(*attrs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modelattribute

I have worked on numerous projects where I have seen both the setting of attributes for a new object in an HTML form and when calling `Model.new(foo: 'bar')`

Which is the *correct* way of doing this in the fashion of "best practices"?

Form:

```
<%= form_for User.new, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :foo, value: "bar" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

Instance Variable:

```
#Obviously this is set in the Controller    
@user = User.new(foo: "bar")

<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i guess `<%= form_for User.new, remote: true do |f| %>` is better if it is in a `partial` and you are calling it on multiple occasions. Also instance variable takes more space.

Answer (score 1):

At first case, when validation of user is not passed, empty form will be rendered, at second case form with filled fields will be rendered. It's because instance variable @user at controller will keep entered values.

So I recommend you to use second variant.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with @Pavel on this. +1

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the form being in a form partial. This way, you don't duplicate the new and the edit.

```
_form.html.erb

<%= form_for user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

This lets you send in the user that you want to render it by.

So in the new.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: {user: @user} %>
```

But it all comes down to the controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't think I was all that clear with my original question... I am trying to figure out the best practice when it comes to setting attributes on a new object either when the object is instantiated or is it preferred to set them in a hidden field in the HTML form?

Comment: If you set them in the form, and do not send them in with hidden fields, they will not be set. I would highly prefer setting them in the create action on the controller.